# How can I add this controls to my project?

Tags: c#

I download a zip file that its have some control with metrial design([this file](https://codeload.github.com/Viki4Tech/MaterialDesign/zip/master)) but i don't know how to add them to my project.

(i don't know English very well so if there are problem please overlook them )

Comment: what did you try to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

in readme file you can see how to use controls:
To implement LollipopUI in your application

1. Add the resources to your project Add Roboto-Medium and Roboto-Regular fonts to resources.Open solution explorer and Right-click on Roboto-Medium => Properties => Change Build Action from "None" to "Embedded source".....Do the same to Roboto-Regular .
2. Add the references add System.Design.dll reference to your project. To do that click on Project tab => Choose Add Reference => Select System.Design and press ok.
3. Include Controls and UIManagers folders to your project.
4. Build your solution.

now you can see "LollipopUI Components" in Toolbox.